# How to keep different files(/versions of files) on local branches and not show them in git status?

Tags: python, django, git, postgresql, python-2.7

Me: I work (develop) on a Django project in a team. And we use postgresql as the database. I had untracked the migrations folders (and files) for obvious reasons.

Problem: Sometimes I work on multiple branches and when there is a difference in the models which extend django.db.models.Model the makemigrations fails.

My approach on the Problem: I decided to have a different database on my machine for each branch. Found out that this could be done using pygit2 (keep the name of database same as that of the branch).

Problem with my approach: The migrations are same in every branch as I have them untracked. I dont want to track migrations because pushing them would disturb the production server migrations.

Requirement: Whenever i switch branch, the migrations should change, but at the same time they should remain not pop up during 'git status'.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think [postgres] tab is relevant here

Comment: Didn't understand all but perhaps a good case to use 'skip-worktree' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree

Comment: @Philippe Skip worktree is definitely something new i came across but it still isnt useful to me. I want the files to change when I switch branch.